# How to access the credentials in Kubernetes for MongoDB with Java?

Tags: java, spring, jenkins, kubernetes

I am working on Java **Springboot** with **MongoDB** using **Kubernetes**. Currently I just hard coded the URI in application properties and I would like to know

how can I access to the MongoDB credentials on Kubernetes with Java?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of passing credentials to Kubernetes pods is to use [secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/) and to expose them to the application either as environment variables, or as a volume. The link above describes in detail how each approach works.

Answer (score 1):

If I properly understood the question, it is *specifically* about Java Spring Boot applications running on Kubernetes.

Few options come to my mind...some not that secure or exclusive to running on Kubernetes but still mentioned here:

- Environment variables with values in the [deployment/pod configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#define-an-environment-variable-for-a-container). Everyone with access to the configuration will be able to see them.

  Use `${<env-var>}` / `${<end-var>:<default-value>}` to access the environment variables in Spring Boot's `application.properties/.yaml` file. For example, if `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD` are two such environment variables:

  ```
  spring.data.mongodb.username = ${DB_USERNAME}
  spring.data.mongodb.password = ${DB_PASSWORD}
  ```

  ...or

  ```
  spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb://${DB_USERNAME}:${DB_PASSWORD}@<host>:<port>/<dbname>
  ```

  This will work regardless whether the application uses `spring.data.mongodb.*` properties or properties with custom names injected in a `@Configuration` class with `@Value`.
- Based on how the Java application is started in the container, [startup arguments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#define-a-command-and-arguments-when-you-create-a-pod) can be defined in the deployment/pod configuration, similarly to the bullet point above.
- Environment variables with values populated from [secret(s)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#define-container-environment-variables-using-secret-data). Access the environment variables from SpringBoot as above.
- [Secrets as files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod) - the secrets will "appear" in a file dynamically added to the container at some location/directory; it would require you to define your own `@Configuration` class that loads  the user name and password from the file using `@PropertySource`.
- The whole `application.properties` could be put in a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/). Notice that the properties will be in clear text. Then [populate a Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#populate-a-volume-with-data-stored-in-a-configmap) with the ConfigMap so that `application.properties` will be added to the container at some location/directory. [Point](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) Spring Boot to that location using `spring.config.location` as env. var, system property, or *program* argument.
- [Spring Cloud Vault](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/reference/html/)
- Some other external vault-type of secure storage - an [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) can fetch the db credentials and make them available to the Java application in a file on a shared volume in the same pod.
- Spring Cloud Config...even though it is unlikely you'd want to put db credentials in its default implementation of the server storage backend - git.